# Can I create download url for my pictures inside firebase storage myself?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase storage, and in documentation, I see the method `getDownloadURL()`, but all it does is attaches some token at the end of the URL?

If my pictures are public, can I simply create the download link myself using a template literal and store it in the Firestore without the token?:

so instead of this:

```
getDownloadURL(userUploadRef).then(async (downloadUrl) => {
const imageUrl = downloadUrl;
// store it to firestore
```

simply do this:

```
const imageUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/routinePhotos%2F${res.data.docRefId}?alt=media`;
const thumbnailUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/routinePhotos%2F${res.data.docRefId}_640x360?alt=media`;
// store links in firestore
```

Because these links are based on the document Id in the Firestore, even if I change the actual picture in the storage, I wouldn't have to update the link in the Firestore document, since these links will always refer to the same location.

1. Can I create a link myself?
2. What is the purpose of the `getDownloadUrl()?`
3. What is the need for the extra token URL at the end of the link, If I can access that file without it anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Can I create the link myself?

No, because that token is generated on the server.

> 2. What is the purpose of the getDownloadUrl()?

Is to get the download of the uploaded file URL, including the token.

> 3. What is the need for the extra token URL at the end of the link, If I can access that file without it anyways?

The token that is added at the end of the URL acts as a security measure to restrict access only to those who know the token. Without it, you cannot access the file. You'll get a permission denied error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Permission denied."
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to access the files without a token, then you should set the rules like this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read; //
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For my use case I need files to be accessible without the token, can I simply change the security rules? And use Firebase App Check for security?

Comment: In that case, please check my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, everything works! So can I use the Firebase App Check for security instead of these tokens?

Comment: Since [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) actually supports Cloud Storage, you might give it a try.

Comment: Hey Ripas55. Can I help you with other information?